# Which d3 layout should I use?

Tags: d3.js

I need to draw a tree with d3.js that has two "roots" and that is "force-directed" The json of this graph (very simple, it's just a trial) is:

```
{
"nodes":
[
    {"name":"node1",
    "children":[
        {"name":"node2", "children":[{"name":"node3"}, {"name":"node4"}]},
        {"name":"node5", "children":[{"name":"node6", "children":[{"name":"node8"}]}, {"name":"node7"}]}
    ]},
    {"name":"node9",
    "children":[
        {"name":"node2", "children":[]}
    ]}
]
```

}

I tried to use the force layout, but it doesn't seem to work. So I thought that maybe I'm using the wrong layout for my goal, but I can't figure out which layout I should use.
My code is:

```
var width = 1200,
height = 800,
graph;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(100)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.05)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("svg:defs").append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", "arrowhead")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 30)
        .attr("refY", -1.5)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("dirGraph.json", function(error, json) {
graph = json;
for(var i=0; i<graph.nodes.length; i++) 
    update(graph.nodes[i]);
})

function update(root) {

var nodes = flatten(root),
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

node = node.data(nodes, function(d){return d.id;});

node.exit().remove();

var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("id", function(d){return d.id;})
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);

nodeEnter.append("circle").attr("r", 20);

nodeEnter.append("text").attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d){return d.name;});

node.select("circle").style("fill", color);

link = link.data(links, function(d){return d.target.id;});

link.exit().remove();

link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d){return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function(d){return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function(d){return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function(d){return d.target.y;})
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)");

  }

  function tick() {

link.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +        d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
});

link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });


node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});

  }

  function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
       : "#c6dbef"; // expanded package
  }

  function flatten(root) {

var nodes = [], i = 0;

function recurse(node) {
    if(node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if(!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
}

recurse(root);

return nodes;

 }

 function click(d) {

if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag

if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
} else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
}

update();

 }
```

My question is: should I use a different layout or should I use the force layout in a different way?

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you want to achieve (maybe you could make a mockup?), but if you want things to be force-directed you have to use the force layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want to do is drawing a graph that is "force-directed", acyclic and with two nodes (the "roots" I was talking about) that have no parents, but that can have some children in common. In the json I've posted, the two "roots" are node1 and node9 and their common child is node2.

Comment: Do you want a [force layout with multiple foci](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021841)?

Comment: Yes, I think this example can help me. Thank you very much!